# programmatically set count of change detection at time angular 8

Tags: angular

I know how to work a change detection. I read more about It.But i have lots of change detection on time which lead to update html.which in turn slows down the browser

Can i set count of change detection at time for component in angular 8?For example if i want one change detection on 2 minute. Is it possible?

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `<child-comp></child-comp>
                <p> {{name}}</p>`,
    styles: [`h2, p {color:#333;}`]
})
export class AppComponent { 
  // a lot of code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to customize when to run change detection you need to inject ChangeDetectorRef and detach.

```
construtor(private changeDetection: ChangeDetectorRef){
  this.changeDetection.detach();
}
```

Then you can use an observable timer to run change detection periodically

```
timer(12000).subscribe(() => this.changeDetection.detectChanges())
```

Don't forget to manage the observable subscription an unsubscribe on component destroy.

Official docs: https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef

**EDIT**

to limit the number of change detection
implement OnChanges.

```
private countChanges =0;

ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges){

 this.countChanges++;
 if(this.countChanges > 1){
   this.changeDetection.detach();
   this.countChanges = 0;
    timer(12000).pipe(take(1)).subscribe(() => this.changeDetection.reattach())
 }

}
```

Comment: this version is bad if we does not have change detection from root component on this time